# How can I grep for a value from a shell variable?

Tags: perl, shell, grep

I've been trying to grep an exact shell 'variable' using word boundaries,

```
grep "\<$variable\>" file.txt
```

but haven't managed to; I've tried everything else but haven't succeeded.

Actually I'm invoking `grep` from a Perl script:

```
$attrval=`/usr/bin/grep "\<$_[0]\>" $upgradetmpdir/fullConfiguration.txt`
```

`$_[0]` and `$upgradetmpdir/fullConfiguration.txt` contains some matching "text".

But `$attrval` is empty after the operation.

Comment: "<" and ">" aren't word boundaries for any grep I'm familiar with. What operating system is this? Are you interested in literally "$variable" or the shell expansion of it? You tagged this with both "shell" and "perl"; which is it?

Comment: I've updated the question, have a look.

Comment: You have to worry about how many times the backslashes are interpreted.  Perl is stripping off the backslashes; the argument that 'grep' sees does not contain any backslashes.  You would need to double the backslashes in the Perl code to get the required effect.

Comment: Also, it would be practically as easy to do that all in Perl as dropping out into shell.  I'm pretty sure there's a module that would do that automatically: f'rinstance http://search.cpan.org/~mneylon/File-Grep-0.02/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@OP, you should do that 'grepping' in Perl. don't call system commands unnecessarily unless there is no choice.

```
$mysearch="pattern";
while (<>){
 chomp;
 @s = split /\s+/;
 foreach my $line (@s){
    if ($line eq $mysearch){
      print "found: $line\n";
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Quite.  In particular, with system commands, you have to worry about which version of the command is installed.  Perl is there to make these worries go away.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the problem here:

file.txt:

```
hello
hi
anotherline
```

Now,

```
mala@human ~ $ export GREPVAR="hi"
mala@human ~ $ echo $GREPVAR
hi
mala@human ~ $ grep "\<$GREPVAR\>" file.txt 
hi
```

What exactly isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Not every grep supports the ex(1) / vi(1) word boundary syntax.

I think I would just do:

```
grep -w "$variable" ...
```

Comment: I think you probably meant to use double quotes there.

Answer (score 0):

Using single quotes works for me in `tcsh`:

```
grep '<$variable>' file.txt
```

I am assuming your input file contains the literal string: `<$variable>`

Comment: That doesn't expand '$variable' which the user requested.  It would also require the exact string, with '<' before and '>' after the text.

Comment: I think Guaurav needs to show a small sample of his input file, his desired output, and confirm that `$variable` should be expanded by the shell.  When more details become available, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `variable=foo` are you trying to `grep` for "foo"? If so, it works for me. If you're trying to `grep` for the variable named "$variable",  then change the quotes to single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

On a recent linux it works as expected. Do could try `egrep` instead

Answer (score 0):

Say you have

```
$ cat file.txt
This line has $variable
DO NOT PRINT ME! $variableNope
$variable also
```

Then with the following program

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -l

use warnings;
use strict;

system("grep", "-P", '\$variable\b', "file.txt") == 0
  or warn "$0: grep exited " . ($? >> 8);
```

you'd get output of

```
This line has $variable
$variable also
```

It uses the [`-P` switch to GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) that matches Perl regular expressions. The feature is still experimental, so proceed with care.

Also note the use of [`system LIST`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) that bypasses shell quoting, allowing the program to specify arguments with Perl's quoting rules rather than the shell's.

You could use the `-w` (or `--word-regexp`) switch, as in

```
system("grep", "-w", '\$variable', "file.txt") == 0
  or warn "$0: grep exited " . ($? >> 8);
```

to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Using single quote it wont work. You should go for double quote

For example:

```
this wont work
--------------
for i in 1
do
grep '$i' file
done

this will work
    --------------
    for i in 1
    do
    grep "$i" file
    done
```